# Algorithm to find smallest N such that N! is divisible by a prime raised to a power

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers

Is there an efficient algorithm to compute the smallest integer N such that N! is divisible by p^k where p is a relatively small prime number and k, a very large integer. In other words,

```
factorial(N) mod p^k == 0
```

If, given N and p, I wanted to find how many times p divides into N!, I would use the well-known formula

```
k = Sum(floor(N/p^i) for i=1,2,...
```

I've done brute force searches for small values of k but that approach breaks down very quickly as k increases and there doesn't appear to be a pattern that I can extrapolate to larger values.

**Edited 6/13/2011**

Using suggestions proposed by Fiver and Hammar, I used a quasi-binary search to solve the problem but not quite in the manner they suggested. Using a truncated version of the second formula above, I computed an upper bound on N as the product of k and p (using just the first term). I used 1 as the lower bound. Using the classic binary search algorithm, I computed the midpoint between these two values and calculated what k would be using this midpoint value as N in the second formula, this time with all the terms being used.

If the computed k was too small, I adjusted the lower bound and repeated. Too big, I first tested to see if k computed at midpoint-1 was smaller than the desired k. If so, midpoint was returned as the closest N. Otherwise, I adjusted the highpoint and repeated.

If the computed k were equal, I tested whether the value at midpoint-1 was equal to the value at midpoint. If so, I adjusted the highpoint to be the midpoint and repeated. If midpoint-1 was less than the desired k, the midpoint was returned as the desired answer.

Even with very large values for k (10 or more digits), this approach works O(n log(n)) speeds.

Comment: Even though Nemo's answer is not really clear, I believe it to be better than the binary search. After all, it's O(1)! Or, to be more precise, as you have to handle the digits, it's O(log k). This problem is directly resolvable, so there is no need to do some iterative computations.

Comment: It's preferable to put to answer into an answer to your own question, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: "10 or more digits" is not "very large" :-).  I have edited my answer to add a Perl implementation.  Seems to work fine even for k with dozens of digits, although I do not know whether the answer is correct.  If you can find a case where it gives the wrong answer I would like to see it.

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer, since it is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formula you mentioned, the sequence of `k` values given fixed `p` and `N = 1,2...` is non-decreasing. This means you can use a variant of binary search to find `N` given the desired `k`.

- Start with `N = 1`, and calculate `k`.
- Double `N` until `k` is greater or equal than your desired `k` to get an upper bound.
- Do a binary search on the remaining interval to find your `k`.

Answer (score 4):

OK this is kind of fun.

Define f(i) = (p^i - 1) / (p - 1)

Write k in a kind of funny "base" where the value of position i is this f(i).

You do this from most-significant to least-significant digit.  So first, find the largest j such that f(j) <= k.  Then compute the quotient and remainder of k / f(j).  Store the quotient as q_j and the remainder as r.  Now compute the quotient and remainder of r / f(j-1).  Store the quotient as q_{j-1} and the remainder as r again.  Now compute the quotient and remainder of r / f(j-2).  And so on.

This generates a sequence q_j, q_{j-1}, q_{j-2}, ..., q_1.  (Note that the sequence ends at 1, not 0.)  Then compute q_j*p^j + q_{j-1}*p^(j-1) + ... q_1*p.  That's your N.

Example:  k = 9, p = 3.  So f(i) = (3^i - 1) / 2.  f(1) = 1, f(2) = 4, f(3) = 13.  So the largest j with f(j) <= 9 is i = 2 with f(2) = 4.  Take the quotient and remainder of 9 / 4.  That's a quotient of 2 (which is the digit in our 2's place) and remainder of 1.

For that remainder of 1, find the quotient and remainder of 1 / f(1).  Quotient is 1, remainder is zero, so we are done.

So q_2 = 2, q_1  = 1.  2*3^2 + 1*3^1 = 21, which is the right N.

I have an explanation on paper for why this works, but I am not sure how to communicate it in text...  Note that f(i) answers the question, "how many factors of p are there in (p^i)!".  Once you find the largest i,j such that j*f(i) is less than k, and realize what  you are really doing is finding the largest j*p^i less than N, the rest kind of falls out of the wash.  In our p=3 example, for instance, we get 4 p's contributed by the product of 1-9, 4 more contributed by the product of 10-18, and one more contributed by 21.  Those first two are just multiples of p^2; f(2) = 4 is telling us that each multiple of p^2 contributes 4 more p's to the product.

[update]

Code always helps to clarify.  Save the following perl script as `foo.pl` and run it as `foo.pl <p> <k>`.  Note that `**` is Perl's exponentiation operator, `bdiv` computes a quotient and remainder for BigInts (unlimited-precision integers), and `use bigint` tells Perl to use BigInts everywhere.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use bigint;

@ARGV == 2
    or die "Usage: $0 <p> <k>\n";

my ($p, $k) = map { Math::BigInt->new($_) } @ARGV;

sub f {
    my $i = shift;
    return ($p ** $i - 1) / ($p - 1);
}

my $j = 0;
while (f($j) <= $k) {
    $j++;
}
$j--;

my $N = 0;

my $r = $k;
while ($r > 0) {
    my $val = f($j);
    my ($q, $new_r) = $r->bdiv($val);
    $N += $q * ($p ** $j);
    $r = $new_r;
    $j--;
}

print "Result: $N\n";

exit 0;
```

Comment: this feels like something that the p-adic norm would help explain

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try binary search for the answer, using the second formula you mentioned?

You only need to consider values for N, for which p divides N, because if it doesn't, then N! and (N-1)! are divided by the same power of p, so N can't be the smallest one.

Answer (score -2):

Consider

I = (p<sup>n</sup>)!

and ignore prime factors other than p. The result looks like

I = p<sup>n</sup> * p<sup>n-1</sup> * p<sup>n-2</sup> * ... * p * 1
I = p<sup>n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... 2 + 1</sup>
I = p<sup>(n<sup>2</sup> +n)/2</sup>

So we're trying to find the smallest n such that

(n<sup>2</sup> +n)/2 >= k

which if I remember the quadratic equation right gives us

**N = p<sup>n</sup>, where n >= (sqrt(1+8k) -1)/2**



(P.S. Does anyone know how to show the radical symbol in markdown?)

**EDIT:**

**This is wrong.** Let me see if I can salvage it...